# Flutter: CustomPainter is not picking up the full size of parent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to fill the required size with a `CustomPaint` widget. My code is as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
//      backgroundColor: Colors.white, //Provider.of<UserData>(context).getSecondryColor(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 10,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                //Before projects get user profile first
                Profile? _profile = await MyDatabase.db.getProfile();
                if (_profile != null) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mySites');
                } else {
                  bool result = await showProfilePrompt(context);
                  if (result) Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/myProfile');
                }
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(color: Colors.deepOrange,),
                  LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context , constraints ) {
                      print (constraints);
                      return CustomPaint(
                          size: Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight),
                          painter: TriangleDraw(context)
                      );
                    },
                  ),
…
```

The problem is that my constraint size on debug console prints as

```
BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=546.4)
```

But as you can see I have added a `Container` with `backgroundColor` to visualise the full size. Please see the actual size of the Stack below:

[image]

My CustomDraw is quite simple: (I know it is not a triangle)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TriangleDraw extends CustomPainter {
  late Paint painter;

  TriangleDraw(BuildContext buildContext) {
    painter = Paint()
      ..color = Theme.of(buildContext).colorScheme.primary
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print('Size: $size');
    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.height, size.width);
    path.lineTo(0, size.width - (size.width/4));
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, painter);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: could you add the full code of CustomDraw?

Comment: Code added above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using LayoutBuilder in wrong place, change it to this:

```
Expanded(
            flex: 10,
            child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  //Before projects get user profile first
                  Profile? _profile = await MyDatabase.db.getProfile();
                  if (_profile != null) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mySites');
                  } else {
                    bool result = await showProfilePrompt(context);
                    if (result) Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/myProfile');
                  }
                },
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    ),
                    CustomPaint(
                        size: Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight),
                        painter: TriangleDraw(context)),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
          )
```

and also change your `CustomDraw` to this:

```
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);// <--- change this line
path.lineTo(0, size.width - (size.width / 4));
path.close();

canvas.drawPath(path, painter);
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work. No change to layout

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @Damandroid

Comment: I changed as per code above. But no still change.

Comment: I updated again, check it out @Damandroid